# Have any good links/articles on job queuing & db sharding?

Tags: sharding, job-queue

Does anyone have good links on how/when/why to use job queuing to scale web apps? Also, articles on db sharding would be useful too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fantastic [presentation](http://www.coderholic.com/the-ultimate-scalability-presentation/) covers lots of scalability issues, including job queueing and db sharing. There are also quite a few stack overflow questions about this:

- [How would I learn more about sharding userdata for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054479/data-sharding)
- [When people talk about scaling a website with 'shards', what do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91710/when-people-talk-about-scaling-a-website-with-shards-what-do-they-mean)
- [Resources for Database Sharding and Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292039/resources-for-database-sharding-and-partitioning)